# Below is the code where I am trying to get the operating system name for multiple system

Tags: powershell

If I give one system, it is working. If I give multiple systems it is showing RPC error. If I give my system twice, then it also is not working. Any idea?

```
Function Get_Systeminfo() {
    $TxtBox.Visible = $false
    $ColName = @{Expression={$_.CSNAME};Label="SERVER NAME"},
               @{Expression={$_.Caption};Label="OS NAME"; width =25},
               @{Expression={$_.OSArchitecture};Label="OS TYPE"}

    $ResBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    $ResBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,50)
    $ResBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480, 280)
    $ResBox.Font = "lucida console"
    $objForm.Controls.Add($ResBox)

    $ResBox.Text = foreach ($list in $TxtBox.Text) {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $list |
            Format-Table $ColName -Auto | Out-String
    }
}

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "SystemInfo"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$TxtBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TxtBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20, 20)
$TxtBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,100)
$TxtBox.Multiline = $true
$objForm.Controls.Add($TxtBox)

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,340)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$OKButton.Add_Click({Get_Systeminfo})

$objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 $ResBox.Text = foreach ($list in $TxtBox.Text){
```

to

```
 $ResBox.Text = foreach ($list in $TxtBox.Lines){
```

and it will genereate output, IF you are giving a single name per line.